# Edit in Browser Option Missing on SharePoint Online documents after Information rights management

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, information-management, information-policy

I have configured Information Rights Management on SharePoint Online Document library,

After the configuration of IRM the word documents can not be edited on the browser,

**Question** Does information rights management prohibits the documents to be edited on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

For the IRM, if you enable it, there is no option to choose edit in browser. It’s a normal behavior.

There is a [UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/601165-suggestion-archive/suggestions/13181193-don-t-let-irm-be-a-limitation-to-edit-documents-in) about this topic, you can take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I missed something when configuring the document library